# Better alternatives For Loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am storing a value in column c based on this criteria. There are 4million rows in my dataframe and this takes 2 days to finish.

```
for ( i in 1:NROW(df)) {
  df$c[i+1] <- df$a[i] + df$b[i] - df$a[i+1]
  print(i)
}
```

Are there any alternatives to this for loop that can accomplish what I am doing much faster. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a real answer, but I think it's worth noting that `print()` is probably going to slow your code down a lot by itself, especially if you print on every iteration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, it's always best to provide some sample data and matching expected output to illustrate what you like to achieve. That will make it a lot easier for the SO community to help.

That aside, you could use `dplyr::lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, c = lag(a) + lag(b) - a)
```

Here is an example based on sample data I created

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:10,
    b = 11:20)

df <- mutate(df, c = lag(a) + lag(b) - a)
df
#    a  b  c
#1   1 11 NA
#2   2 12 10
#3   3 13 11
#4   4 14 12
#5   5 15 13
#6   6 16 14
#7   7 17 15
#8   8 18 16
#9   9 19 17
#10 10 20 18
```

You can confirm that indeed `c[i+1] = a[i] + b[i] - a[i+1]`.

---

### Benchmark analysis

Let's compare the following three methods in terms of performance/runtime

1. using `dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::mutate`
2. using base R (thanks @nicola),
3. using `data.table::shift`

We use sample data consisting of `10^6` entries for `a` and `b`.

```
set.seed(2017)
df <- data.frame(
    a = sample(100, 10^6, replace = T),
    b = sample(100, 10^6, replace = T))

library(microbenchark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    method_lag = {
        df <- mutate(df, c = lag(a) + lag(b) - a)
    },
    method_base = {
        df$c <- NA
        df$c[-1] <- df$a[-nrow(df)] + df$b[-nrow(df)] - df$a[-1]
    },
    method_shift = {
        df$c <- shift(df$a) + shift(df$b) - df$a
    })
#Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#   method_lag 19.88495 21.81414 29.30085 23.83718  26.61746 107.04355   100  b
#  method_base 51.00888 56.29822 90.05291 60.65321 128.79227 208.80537   100   c
# method_shift 10.86351 12.51993 18.34094 14.24705  16.88488  92.83246   100 a

autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: It should be nice to also include a `base` alternative, given that here `dplyr` is not necessary. Something like `df$c<-NA;df$c[-1] <- df$a[-nrow(df)] + df$b[-nrow(df)] - df$a[-1]`.

Comment: @nicola I would use diff.

Comment: @nicola Thanks. I've added a benchmark analysis of three methods: base R, using `dplyr::lag`, and using `data.table::shift`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, Thanks that saved 3 days of waiting for the for loop to complete.

Answer (score 0):

loops in high level programing languages are always an issue for large operations. in addition to Maurits answer if you are familiar with `C++` you can use `rcpp` package to compile `c++` codes for `R` which are much more faster.
In addition `print` (as a progress shower) in `C++` is much more optimum than pure `R` printing. [See Example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rcpp_sydney-rug_jul2013.pdf)

You can Also cast `R` (Numeric Vector and Matrix)  to `C++11` std `<std>` vectors and use parallel processing (if your hardware support it) for much better usage of hardware.